# flutter: NoSuchMethodError during debugging with breakpoints

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

I'm currently playing with [flame](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame), a small 2D game engine based on flutter. My code contains a rather strange Heisenbug: It works fine if you start it via `run` or `debug`. But if you set a breakpoint, it throws an error

```
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'cls' was called on null.
```

Although I don't think that this is related to flame, I was not able to reproduce the problem with flutter alone. So I'm including a minimal version of my flame-based code. It simply paints the phone-screen with a gray background color:

**main.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:temp/game.dart';

void main(){
  MyGame game = MyGame(); // error thrown here
  runApp(game.widget);
}
```

**game.dart:**

```
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'dart:ui';

class MyGame extends Game{
  Size screenSize;

  @override
  void render(Canvas canvas) {
    Rect screenRect = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
    Paint screenPaint = Paint();
    screenPaint.color = Color.fromARGB(255, 100, 100, 100);

    canvas.drawRect(screenRect, screenPaint);
  }

  @override
  void update(double t) {
  }

  @override
  void resize(Size size) {
    super.resize(size);
    screenSize = size;
  }
}
```

If you want to run this, you also have to add flame to your pubspec:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  flame: ^0.10.2
```

My bug happens everytime I set a breakpoint in the render method of `MyGame` and start debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I can not reproduce this on `flame: ^0.22.0` so you can just upgrade to that version and it should work fine.